# Vectors transforming under change of coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

I was watching a lecture on tensors and the professor said that a defining feature of a vector $v$ is that it transforms under a coordinate transformation $x^{\mu} \rightarrow x^{\mu'}$ as

$$v^{\mu'}(x^{\mu'}) \equiv \frac{\partial x^{\mu'} }{\partial x^\mu} v^{\mu}(x^{\mu}(x^{\mu'})) $$

Basically the last last term on the right hand side is the $x^{\mu}$ coordinates expressed in terms of $x^{\mu'}$ coordinates.

I am trying to understand this in $\mathbb R^2$ for the Cartesian and Polar coordinates. If the $x^{\mu'} \equiv (x,y)$ and  $x^{\mu} \equiv (r,\theta)$, then I get

$$\bigg(\begin{matrix}x\\y \end{matrix}\bigg) \equiv 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
\cos\theta&-r\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&r\cos\theta 
\end{matrix}\bigg] \bigg(\begin{matrix}r\\\theta \end{matrix}\bigg)$$

which doesn't work out to be true. Can you please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Link to lecture? Minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This transformation equation applies to a vector $v$ that "lives at" at the point $x$ (i.e., is in the tangent space at $x$). The point $x$ is described by the coordinates $(x, y)$ or $(r, \theta)$, but these coordinate tuples are not vectors *at* $x$. Examples of vectors at $x$ are $(dx, dy)$ and $(dr, d\theta)$, and your matrix equation applies to them:

$$\bigg(\begin{matrix}dx\\dy \end{matrix}\bigg) =
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
\cos\theta&-r\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&r\cos\theta 
\end{matrix}\bigg] \bigg(\begin{matrix}dr\\d\theta \end{matrix}\bigg)$$

Comment: This is right. So many times I see people thinking that coordinates are vectors, and it leads to so much confusion when we have a vector space defined over those coordinates.

Comment: For a general manifold, as opposed to flat space, why do you have to think of vectors and tensors as living at a point? Well, think about the curved surface of the Earth. A vector pointing north in New York is different from a vector pointing north in Tokyo. A lot of differential geometry is about how to compare vectors at different points.

Comment: Right. I see a similar confusion in introductory EM in expressing vectors using the unit vectors $\hat r$, $\hat\theta$, and $\hat\phi$ depends on where the vector is located.

Comment: If I have to be pedantic, the vectors living at the point $p=(x,y)$ are $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$.

Comment: @Gonenc Mogol Aren’t they covectors? The OP’s transformation rule was for contravariant vectors, not covariant ones.

Comment: No it is exactly the other way around. Vectors are $\partial_x$, and covectors are $\mathrm d x$. You can see this by the definition of tangen space as the "derivatives of curves" at some point. See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Basis_of_the_tangent_space_at_a_point)

Comment: I think you are using mathematicians’ definition of contravariance and covariance, and I am using physicists’.

Comment: Physicists tend to be interested in how the components change.

Comment: As explained at https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/PlanetPhysics/Covariance_and_Contravariance, “A major potential cause of confusion is that this duality of covariance/contravariance intervenes every time discussion of a vector or tensor quantity is represented by its components. This causes discussion in the mathematics and physics literature often apparently to be using opposite conventions.” Physicists call $dx^\mu$ contravariant and $\partial_\mu$ covariant.

Comment: Physicists *should* refer to $v^\mu$, $dx^\mu$, etc. as “the contravariant *components* of a vector”, but they are sloppy and call it “a contravariant vector”.

Comment: I see the distinction now. I was hoping for some clarification. 1) Is the coordinate tuple $(x,y)$ a tensor at all? 2) Moreover, in the language of tensor calculus, $\mathrm{d}$ is the exterior derivative which has been defined to act only on differential forms ($(0,n)$ tensors). Does this mean that $x$ and $y$ are each considered to be scalar functions ($(0,0) tensors$). If so, what are $x$ and $y$ considered a function of? 3) The exterior derivative acting on a $n$-form converts it to an ($n+1$)-form. However, $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$ are not components of a differential form.

Comment: (1) No. (2) and (3) I am using dx as a simple differential like you learned in Calculus I, not as an exterior derivative applied to x. Think of (dx, dy) as an infinitesimal vector from (x,y) to (x+dx, y+dy). If your class is using the modern mathematical notions of differential forms, then ignore what I'm saying because I'm being too old-fashioned.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. May be I should have included this in the original question but this is the lecture series I'm using. And this is the introduction of the exterior derivative. https://youtu.be/Ki-jNDyNhOQ?list=PLrbYZnU7vahLdijxQnWO2eBk3XTJMvO4a&t=4157